# How to hide fields by default with webform-7.x-4.0-alpha6

Tags: 7, webforms

How do I make conditional fields work properly with **webform-7.x-4.0-alpha6** ?

1. **Expected behaviour :** I created a webform content with a radio button field called "Assurance" (yes/no). The wanted behaviour is : when the assurance value is not "yes" hide a fieldset called "assurance information". By default "Assurance" has no value, so "assurance information" has to be hidden.
2. **Unexcpected result :** Currently my problem is that "assurance informations" is visible by default, and when i click on Assurance whatever the value is "assurance informations" disapear and never appears.

Can anybody find a clue ? thanks in advance.

Comment: Since you're using the alpha branch, and your question suggests that this is a problem specific to webform, you should consider asking in the module's issue queue rather than here.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @PatrickKenny, I'll do that too... to increase my answer chance ;)